# render threaded comment tree in Jinja template

Tags: python, tree, jinja2

I am trying to implement threaded comments in my flask project which I want to look like this:

```
comment1
    reply1
        reply4
            reply6
        reply5
    reply2
    reply3
comment2
```

For the above example, I have comments like this:

```
comments = { 'comment1':['reply1', 'reply2', 'reply3'],
             'reply1':['reply4', 'reply5'],
             'reply4':['reply6'],
             'reply2':[],
             'reply3':[],
             'reply5':[],
             'reply6':[],
             'comment2':[],
            }
```

The key-value pair is comment:their direct replies

After this I tried to build a list based tree for every root comment i.e. comment1, comment2 etc. for example for `comment1` I've got a tree like:

```
['reply1', ['reply4', ['reply6', []], 'reply5', []], 'reply2', [], 'reply3', []]
```

Now, I don't know how to render these comments/replies as threads and multilevel indentation. How should I parse this tree in Jinja template and render the comments/replies ? Is it necessary to construct a list based tree for every comment as I've done here OR will the dictionary of comments be sufficient for the desired implementation ?

Comment: why don't  you put the comments in a tree structure (you may have to write something yourself or look for a library). your nodes should know their dephts. i'd recomment not putting too much logic in your templates...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First decide how the HTML should look like (I presume you want to generate HTML), then design your template, then write the Python code to generate the appropriate data structure.  Don't attempt to implement any complex tree traversal stuff in your templates.

One example with nested HTML lists:

```
<ul>
{% for node in nodes %}
{% if node.indent %}
  <li><ul>
{% elif node.outdent %}
  </ul></li>
{% elif node.content %}
  <li>{{ node.content }}</li>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This would require a flattened tree structure like this:

```
{ "nodes": [
  { "content": "hi" },
  { "indent": True },
  { "content": "how do you do" },
  { "outdent": True },
  { "content": "hi again" },
]}
```

Comment: After I posted this question, I tried something very much similar to your suggestion and it worked. Therefore, I'll accept your answer. Thanks :)